# Disabling password expiry for auto login User Linux

Tags: linux, debian, password, pam

I have a unattended system which runs under `test` login. Recently, I enabled password expiry for 90 days.

All I am expecting is if someone login manually with user `test` after 90 days it should prompt user for password change. For `lightdm` auto login It should just login irrespective of days.

Currently using **PAM** config.